# How to create a singleton object in Scala with runtime params

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a singleton object with parameters which are specified by runtime.
Example:

```
object NetworkPusher {
  val networkAdress = ???
  ...
 }
```

Imagine the networkAdress param comes from the command-line. How can I make a workaround to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do this. Object definitions need to be completely specified at compile time. However, if you want to just set the value of the network address from the command line args, you can use the args array and pass in the value of of the network address in the NetworkPusher constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Singletons are initialized lazily.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Net {
  val address = Config.address
}
object Config { var address = 0L }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Net
defined object Config

scala> Config.address = "1234".toLong
Config.address: Long = 1234

scala> Net.address
res0: Long = 1234
```

FWIW.

Comment: I never knew about `:pa` paste mode! Great tip!

Answer (score 0):

This is rather convention over configuration approach.
But it is thread safe and adds obligatory initialisation requirement:

```scala
    abstract class NetworkPusher() {
      private var networkAddress: String = ""
      def setNetworkAddr(addr: String) = networkAddress = addr
      def getNetworkAddr() = networkAddress
    }

    object NetworkPusherFactory {
    
      private var initOnceReady: NetworkPusher => Unit = _
    
      private lazy val initializedInstance = {
        val pusher =  new NetworkPusher(){}
        initOnceReady(pusher)
        pusher
      }
      def create(init: NetworkPusher => Unit): NetworkPusher = {
        initOnceReady = init
        initializedInstance
      }
    }
    
    object Main {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val networkAddr = "A.D.D.R" // args[0]
        val onePusher = NetworkPusherFactory.create(
          instance => instance.setNetworkAddr(networkAddr)
        )
        println(s"using ${onePusher.getNetworkAddr}")
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `lazy`:

```
object Program {

  var networkAdress: String = _

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    networkAdress = args(0)
    println(NetworkPusher.networkAdress)
  }

  object NetworkPusher {
    lazy val networkAdress = Program.networkAdress
  }
}
```

Comment: lazy here is not needed, object is initialized lazily