# Updatable singleton object in Scala

Tags: scala, singleton, immutability, mutable

I would like a singleton object in Scala that has an updatable field.
Is there a better solution than what I have below that doesn't use a `var`?

```
class Foo {

  def setFoo(newFoo: String): Unit = {
    Foo.foo = newFoo
  }

  def getFoo: String = {
    Foo.foo
  }
}

object Foo {
  var foo = "foo"
}
```

Comment: You can't change an object without it being mutable in some way, i.e. containing a var.

Comment: No idea what you really need, but reminiscent of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801150/how-to-create-a-singleton-object-in-scala-with-runtime-params

Answer (score 0):

If you want mutability (i.e a variable being constantly updated), `var` is your only option.

But you can write it in an *"immutable way"* in which `set` means creating a new immutable instance:

```
class Foo(foo: String) {}

object Foo {
    create(foo: String): Foo = new Foo(foo)
}

// ...
Foo foo = Foo.create("foo")
val bar = foo.foo  // "foo"
```

Comment: Your example is no longer a singleton? I would like every access to Foo to be the current value of foo.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with your original implementation, but shield your mutable singleton to the associated class:

```
class Foo {

  def setFoo(newFoo: String): Unit = {
    Foo.foo = newFoo
  }

  def getFoo: String = {
    Foo.foo
  }
}

private [Foo] object Foo {
  var foo = "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution to what you have that does use `var` could be simply

```
object Foo {
  var foo = "foo"
}
```

just this, you don't need the class and those setters, compiler will generate them for you.
Now you can just do:

```
Foo.foo = "bar"
```

or read value like this

```
Foo.foo
```

I don't see a way to have mutable state in object without vars though.